# Deferred animation in array: how to?

Tags: jquery, promise, fade, deferred

I'm making a small jQuery game where, when the user clicks on a div, many other divs may disappear.

What I've done so far is a loop in the "click" event:

```
function makeDisappear(idx) {                                                      
    return $('img[data-idx="'+idx+'"]').fadeOut(5000, function() {               
    }).promise();                                                                
}                         
$('.mydiv').click(function() {                                              
    /*
    ... code do fill tabResult (which is an array)
    */
    var tabFadingOut=[];                                         
    for (var i=0; i<tabResult.length; i++) {                     
        tabFadingOut.push(makeDisappear(tabResult[i]));            
    }                                                            
    $.when.apply($, tabFadingOut).done(function() {              
        console.log('DONE');
    });                                                          
})
```

If you read the code, i create promise() objects and put them in tabResult (which is an array).
Then I try to send this array to .when() and it doesn't work. I want 'DONE' to appear in the console log... any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Not sure of the meaning of this `$('mydiv')`....if you are pointing to a class, it should be `$('.mydiv')`

Comment: suggest you create a simple demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates the issue

Comment: @RobertRozas You're right, it's a more complex selector I wanted to simplify for the sample because I think it's not relevant.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/ben1729/bcq3y9nv/1/

Comment: Can include `html` , `css` , `tabResult` `js` at OP ?

Comment: @bm1729 May I ask you to answer here so I can check your question as valid? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine to me. Please see the working fiddle:

```
$(function() {

function makeDisappear(idx) {                                                      
    return $('div[data-idx="'+idx+'"]').fadeOut(5000, function() {               
    }).promise();                                                                
}                         
$('.mydiv').click(function() {
    var tabResult = [1, 2, 3];
    var tabFadingOut=[];                                         
    for (var i=0; i<tabResult.length; i++) {                     
        tabFadingOut.push(makeDisappear(tabResult[i]));            
    }                                                            
    $.when.apply($, tabFadingOut).done(function() {              
        console.log('DONE');
    });                                                          
});

});
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ben1729/bcq3y9nv/1/